# Error al crear un Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Estoy tratando de crear el siguiente disparador:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `smdraux_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `smdraux` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF(LENGTH(NEW.llamante) = (4) AND NEW.nombreinterlocutor1 NOT LIKE `VM Channel%`
    AND NEW.nombreinterlocutor1 NOT LIKE `U10%` AND NEW.nombreinterlocutor1 NOT LIKE `Nuevo` 
    AND NEW.nombreinterlocutor1 NOT LIKE `Elvira` AND NEW.nombreinterlocutor1 NOT LIKE `Contact Center` 
    AND NEW.nombreinterlocutor1 NOT IN (SELECT nombreagente FROM agente)) THEN

    INSERT INTO agente(nombreagente, fechaderegistro)
    VALUES(NEW.nombreinterlocutor1, NOW());
END //
```

Pero estoy obteniendo el error:

> "#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintaxis cerca 'END' en la linea
>   10"

Lo cual resulta muy ambiguo para mi que es la primera vez que trabajo con triggers. He intentado poner la expresión "// DELIMITER;" después del 'END' pero me manda el mismo error.

Comment: justo después del `END` prueba colocando solo `DELIMITER;`

Comment: Si hago eso me da el siguiente error: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'DELIMITER' en la linea 11

Comment: También ya lo había intentado. Me manda el mismo error que menciono en el problema.

Comment: Probaste Iniciando con un DELIMITER $$ y terminando con un END $$ DELIMITER; https://stackoverflow.com/a/5372987/6388106

Comment: Si ya lo probé y no funciona, obtengo el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no finaliza el condicional `IF` con `END IF;` antes de `END//`.

Además:

- ¿Necesita [`LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) o [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)?.
- ¿Por qué usa ` para cadenas de texto, no sería, por ejemplo, `'U10%'` en vez de ` `U10%` `?.

Comment: Efectivamente, el error era porque no cerraba la condicional IF, muchas gracias. Respondiendo a tus preguntas, sí necesito que sea lenght porque quiero el tamaño de la cadena y uso `U10%` porque estoy usando phpmyadmin y esa es la forma correcta de ponerlo. Si pongo 'U10%' lo marca como error.

Comment: @Nancy: Recuerde, `LENGTH` retorna la longitud de la cadena medida en bytes mientras que `CHAR_LENGTH` retorna la longitud de la cadena medida en carácteres. La cadena `\`U10%\`` es distinta de `'U10%'`, ver ejemplos en [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCSdJBCy72be3vGgdq6TVa/0).

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, siendo así, lo cambiaré por CHAR_LENGTH